# Getting IP out of TimedOut Pingreply

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asynchronous, ping

I'm pinging a list of Domains (between 1000 - 10000) and have my App count how many are Online and how many are Offline. The issue I'm having is that I would like to make a list with the IP addresses of the Timeout machine's. Is there a way to do that?

```
public async void PingCompletedMethod(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Sorts results of ping process 
            PingReply rep = e.Reply;

            try
            {
                if (e.Error != null)
                {
                    // Counts number of unreachable endpoints
                    errorPings++;
                    ErrorPing.Text = Convert.ToString(errorPings);
                    ErrorPing.Background = Brushes.OrangeRed;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Counts Pings that were succesfull 
                    successPings++;
                    SuccessPing.Text = Convert.ToString(successPings);
                }

                // Counts Online/Offline responses
                if (rep.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    regOnline++;
                    onlineResult.Text = Convert.ToString(regOnline) + " Endpoints Online";
                    onlineResult.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
                }
                else if (rep.Status == IPStatus.TimedOut)
                {
                    // exportList.Add(Convert.ToString(rep.Address));  
                    regOffline++;
                    offlineResult.Text = Convert.ToString(regOffline) + " Endpoints Offline";
                    offlineResult.Background = Brushes.Orange;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                regOffline++;
            }
```

When I try the to get rep.Address under the TimedOut loop I get 0.0.0.0 for every entry. If same added to Success loop I get the IP's. I would like to either get the IP or the domain name of the TimedOut pings.

Here's the ping:

```
foreach (string regOne in regOneList)
            {
                System.Threading.AutoResetEvent autores = new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false);
                Ping pingasync = new Ping();
                pingasync.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(PingCompletedMethod);
                pingasync.SendAsync(regOne, 1000);
                autores.WaitOne(1);
            }
```

Thanks in advance Peter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your domain name as user state like this:

```
pingasync.SendAsync(regOne, 1000, regOne);
```

Then in `PingCompletedMethod` you can get it like this:

```
var reg = (string) e.UserState;
```

Side note: it seems you think you are passing timeout with this code:

```
 pingasync.SendAsync(regOne, 1000);
```

But actually you are passing number "1000" as user state. To pass timeout you need to call:

```
 pingasync.SendAsync(regOne, 1000, null);
```

Default timeout is 5 seconds, so your current code pings with that timeout and not with 1 second as you might have expected.

Comment: Thank you so much that worked (Also thanks for the timeout tip)!

Comment: I used it, this way:                             `exportList.Add(Convert.ToString(e.UserState);`